# Swift: Can't dismiss view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I have a SwiftUI project in which I'm presenting a view controller to display an advertisement via MoPub.

Everything works as expected except one thing: when I tap the ad's close button, the ad itself closes but the black screen behind the ad continues to show. I guess the view controller is not being dismissed (but the completion block for `dismiss` does run).

Here's my code:

```
class InterstitialAds: UIViewController, MPInterstitialAdControllerDelegate {
    var moPubView: MPInterstitialAdController?
    
    func viewControllerForPresentingModalView() -> UIViewController! {
        return self
    }
    
    //Called when you tap the ad's close button:
    func interstitialWillDismiss(_ interstitial: MPInterstitialAdController) {
        dismissControllerWithoutReward()
    }
    
    
    func showAd() {
        let topViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController
        
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        
        topViewController?.present(self, animated: true) {}
    }
 
    
    func dismissControllerWithoutReward() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            print("dismissControllerWithoutReward()") //Successfully prints to console
        }
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let adId = "4f117153f5c24fa6a3a92b818a5eb630" //Test ad unit

        self.moPubView = MPInterstitialAdController(forAdUnitId: adId)

        if let v = self.moPubView {
            v.delegate = self
            v.loadAd()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { 
                v.show(from: self)
            }
        }
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
}
```

**Question:**
Why isn't the view controller being dismissed, despite the successful call to `dismiss`?

Thank you!

**Edit:**
Interestingly, if I wait 0.5 seconds before trying to dismiss the view controller, it dismisses as desired. So, now I've got this code in `interstitialWillDismiss(_:)` (but I still want to know *why* this is happening):

```
func interstitialWillDismiss(_ interstitial: MPInterstitialAdController) {
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
      self.dismissControllerWithoutReward()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting clear implementation and expected behavior you should wrap `InterstitialAds` controller in `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, then connect you SwiftUI side with some `InterstitialAdsView` which implements from `UIViewControllerRepresentable` via some `isPresented` flag binding.

Short example:

```swift
class InterstitialAds: UIViewController {

    let onFlowCompleted: () -> Void

    init(onFlowCompleted: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.onFlowCompleted = onFlowCompleted

        // ...
    }

    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        onFlowCompleted()

        // or somewhere else ...
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {

    @State var shouldShowInterstitialView = false

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            shouldShowInterstitialView = true
        } label: {
            Text("Show Ad")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $shouldShowInterstitialView) {
            InterstitialAdsView {
                shouldShowInterstitialView = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct InterstitialAdsView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    // @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    // or
    // @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    // or
    let onFlowCompleted: () -> Void

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> InterstitialAds {
        InterstitialAds(onFlowCompleted: onFlowCompleted)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: InterstitialAds, context: Context) {
        // update if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this approach already, and found that presenting the ad via SwiftUI view caused it to load poorly (program kind of sputters as the ad is shown). Any idea how to make it work with `present`, `dismiss`, etc., like I have in my question? Thanks!